# I want the user only enter the password once, so they never have to enter it again in the future

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I use http basic authentication. The app is for mobile only, and I don't want the user to have to keep logging in every time they open the page. Is there any way to store the user/pass for future uses of the app. I don't really need it to ever expire, but I just want to at least keep the logging in to very minimum after there first visit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS at least doesn't remember this kind of credentials. If you're set on using http basic auth, you could visit the site using a URL like http://username:password@domain.com/ and save it as a bookmark if you're comfortable having the password saved in the bookmarks.

Comment: you can base64 encode the username:password portion of the string, at least it won't be 'easily' read